# string returned from servlet not correct

Tags: android, servlets

I am facing a weird problem of not able to read a servlet response properly.

The servlet on my jetty webserver returns data like this :

```
resp.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
resp.setContentType("text/plain");
resp.setContentLength(1024);
resp.getWriter().write("DeviceAndNumberAlreadyRegistered");
```

My android app reads the response like this :

```
InputStream is = httpEntity.getContent();
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
        is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
String line = null;
 while((line=reader.readLine())!=null){
 sb.append(line);
 }
is.close();
return sb.toString();
```

Printing the value on Logcat, I can see that the response value (sb.toString()) is the same as what my servlet returned("DeviceAndNumberAlreadyRegistered"). I have also verified that there are no spaces, using trim().

**The problem is if i try to compare the value in my android app in an IF block, it doesn't validate it to TRUE** i.e.  the below code returns false :

```
if(result == "DeviceAndNumberAlreadyRegistered")
```

It doesn't matter what text my servlet returns, it just doesn't validate to TRUE in an IF block. Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use equels to check the string.

"==" only return true when they are the same object, i guess?